# Groovy: Read CSV File without using external library, put column into array

Tags: csv, groovy

My CSV file:

```
Created Date,User Name,Email Address,First Name,Last Name
?20-05-2020,Test1,test1@abc.con,Test,1
20-05-2020,test2,test2@abc.com,Test,2
20-05-2020,Test3,test3@abc.com,Test,3
```

I want to get all the email address and put it in Array + Without using external reference/ Library.

Please help.

Comment: Please show us your code what you have created in order to we can help you.

Comment: Note that sometimes CSV can be really tricky, so its better to use an external library despite your requirement. If you're running in CI or something (it looks like you're trying to parse test reports) you can probably use Grape: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html

Answer (score 1):

Not using a library is a recipe for disaster. There will almost end up being entries that contain commas or whatever the actual separator is, and Excel is notorious for creating corrupted CSVs (non-standard is what it Excels at)

The beauty of Groovy scripts is that they are standalone files that can reach out to the world without requiring any other infrastructure except Groovy being installed.

Using Grape, you can automatically indicate that you want to use a 3rd party library and not worry about jar files, classpaths or installing dependencies.

```
@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-csv', version='1.8')
```

Now you can import the relevant CSV classes you want and just use them.

Comment: Just a heads-up, the OP has a requrement to not use external libs. This could be for one of a variety of reasons. Grape does not always work as advertised - ever tried this in an IDE behind a corporate NTLM proxy? It's a nightmare. It also doesn't work without significant tweaking in SoapUI.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you parse the csv without a library:

```
new File("src/data.csv").splitEachLine(",") { line ->
    println "CreatedDate: ${line[0]}; UserName: ${line[1]}"
}
```

For adding the values to a List, you can do it in the normal way inside the closure.

Comment: This is returing header of the files as well. Is it possible where I can get only the content of the column not the header.

Comment: See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19413469/3355860